# Problemas consultas complejas firebase con python

Tags: python, firebase, flask

buen tardes compañero estoy tratando de hacer una consulta compleja en firebase estoy siguiendo este git https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#database

este es mi codigo :

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config) 
db = firebase.database()
id = '100'
us = db.child("user").order_by_child("name").limit_to_first(10).get()
print(us)
```

esta consulta me deberia de traer un limite de 10 usuarios de la base de datos.
pero me esta saliendo este error:

```
  File "/home/dev06/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 264, in get
    raise_detailed_error(request_object)
  File "/home/dev06/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 448, in raise_detailed_error
    raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://datacreditoprueba.firebaseio.com/user.json?orderBy=%2522name%2522&limitToFirst=2] {
  "error" : "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"
}
```

alguien que me pueda ayudar, se lo agradecería
feliz tarde

Comment: No se si puede ser la causa concreta de este problema pero Firebase ni Pyrebace  son oficialmente compatibles con Python 2.x  ["Pyrebase was written for python 3 and will not work correctly with python 2."](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#python-version) y estás usando Pyton 2: "/home/dev06/.local/lib/python2.7..."

Comment: De cualquier forma a Python 2 le quedan cuatro meses y medio de soporte oficial, va siendo hora de pasarse a Python 3 a no se que se tenga una razón muy concreta  para no hacerlo, ya hay un número relevante de librerías que no ofrecen soporte para Python 2 y esto va a ir en aumento.

Comment: gracias FjSevilla por contestar.

Comment: hola FJSevilla instale python 3.6 pero cuando lo intento correr me sale el mismo error, ahora lo que intentare es elegir la version  de 3.6 por defecto para ver si puedo resolverlo, pero si tienes alguna idea seria mejor

Comment: hola FJSevilla ya pude cambiar la version de python pero ahora me salen estas dos excepciones

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev04/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 503, in raise_detailed_error
    request_object.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/dev04/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://datacreditoprueba.firebaseio.com/user.json?orderBy=%22name%22

Comment: y la segunda es esta
  File "/home/dev04/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 507, in raise_detailed_error
    raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://datacreditoprueba.firebaseio.com/user.json?orderBy=%22name%22] {
  "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"name\", for path \"/user\", to the rules"
}

Comment: ¿Has definido el indice adecuadamente para "name"? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-defining-indexes

Answer (score 0):

**Efectivamente faltaba el índice**, con esto se resuelve el problema con las consultas complejas que tenía

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "user": {
      ".indexOn": "cc"    
    },
    "telefono": {
      ".indexOn": "cc"
    }
  }
}
```